# Complete Observable depending on last value emitted

Tags: rxjs

In my application with have tons of multiple-step-processes. Imagine something like

"opening a document to edit it, changes the state of the document in one of multiple ways.
The user is
a) to be informed, that the document will be changed by this action, and

b) has to decide (sometimes) in which way to change the document."

Since this process is by its nature asyncronous we have the whole thing in a chain of `pipe`-statements.

Now to my question. I am looking for a way to stop the chain at any point if the user decides to stop the execution of the update.
Currently I have the switchMap statement return a self-completing Observable (as seen in the marked line below).

But I was wondering if there is another way, so close the Observable, so that there is no memory leak, without havin multiple Subjects everywhere in my code so to the tried an trusted `ngUnsubscribe$`-thing.

Something like:

```js
openWarnUserDialog().afterClosed().pipe(
  switchMap((proceed: boolean) => 
    proceed ? 
      openChooseChangeDialog().afterClosed() : 
      new Observable<MyType>(sub => sub.complete()), //  <---
  switchMap(chosenChange => this.service.updateDocumentState(chosenChange))
).subscribe( ... );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/takeWhile) to complete the stream when a condition fails:

```js
openWarnUserDialog().afterClosed().pipe(
  takeWhile(proceed => !!proceed),
  switchMap(() => openChooseChangeDialog().afterClosed())
  switchMap(chosenChange => this.service.updateDocumentState(chosenChange))
).subscribe( ... );
```

Comment: Yes! THIS! Exactly this. It was so unbelievable to me that there was no operator for this. Thanks a lot <3